# Error Inflating Class when Programmatically Adding Material TextInputLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have a button that when you click it, it should programmatically inflate the view with a layout that contains a material exposed dropdown, which is supposed to consist of a TextInputLayout and AutoCompleteTextView contained within that. When I click the add button, the app crashes and I get an error like this:

```
E/ThemeUtils: View class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.csmith.bakingapp, PID: 19477
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.csmith.bakingapp:layout/timer: Binary XML file line #8 in com.csmith.bakingapp:layout/timer: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8 in com.csmith.bakingapp:layout/timer: Error inflating class <unknown>

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.csmith.bakingapp:layout/design_text_input_end_icon: Binary XML file line #18 in com.csmith.bakingapp:layout/design_text_input_end_icon: Error inflating class <unknown>
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in com.csmith.bakingapp:layout/design_text_input_end_icon: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

I am inflating my layout like this:

```
private fun addStep() {
    when (currentOption) {
        getString(R.string.step) -> {
            val layoutInflater : LayoutInflater = context?.applicationContext?.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            stepsContainer = currentView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_steps_container)
            val newView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.step, null)
            newView.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.delete_step).setOnClickListener { view -> deleteStep(view) }
            val stepOne : LinearLayout = newView.findViewById(R.id.step_field_layout)
            stepOne.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.step_field).hint = getString(R.string.step_number, stepNumber)
            stepsContainer.addView(stepOne, stepNumber - 1)
            stepNumber++
        }
        getString(R.string.timer) -> {
            val layoutInflater : LayoutInflater = context?.applicationContext?.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
            stepsContainer = currentView.findViewById(R.id.recipe_steps_container)
            val newView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.timer, null)
            timeUnitsMenu = newView.findViewById(R.id.time_units_menu)
            val timer : LinearLayout = newView.findViewById(R.id.timer_field_layout)
            val timeUnits = resources.getStringArray(R.array.time_units)
            val arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(requireContext(), R.layout.dropdown_menu_item, timeUnits)
            timeUnitsMenu.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
            stepsContainer.addView(timer, stepNumber - 1)
            stepNumber++
        }
    }
    stepsScrollView.post { stepsScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN) }
}
```

The error comes from the R.string.timer switch case on the line where I am actually doing the inflating. The timer layout file looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/timer_field_layout"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/options_menu_container"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:hint="@string/unit_hint">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/time_units_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/minutes"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The theme I am using for the app inherits `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`. Any help figuring out why this is happening would be appreciated

**Edit:**

So after doing more playing around and trying to implement a Spinner, I think I have a little better of an idea what's happening. So the spinner works and doesn't crash, but I still get the same error as the first error listed above except it is for a MaterialTextView instead of an AppCompatTextView. I think when the view is being inflated, the TextViews are being converted into a different type of TextView and the theming of those converted TextViews is conflicting with the set theme for the app. In case it's relevant, this is the layout for the dropdown_menu_option:

```
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="10dp"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"/>
```

**Edit 2:**

I was asked for my styles.xml file so here it is:

```
<resources>
<style name="homeButtons" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">125dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">125dp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="iconGravity">textTop</item>
    <item name="iconPadding">20dp</item>
    <item name="iconSize">40dp</item>
    <item name="cornerRadius">15dp</item>
</style>
<style name="homeButtonsRow">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">40dp</item>
</style>
<style name="roundedImageViewRounded">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

and while not asked for here is my themes.xml as well:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.BakingApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Check you styles.xml for current theme, and also share it here.

Comment: It has been added to the description